# SSIS package loses .NET provider password even though EncryptSensitiveWithPassword is enabled

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2016

I have a new SSIS project developed in VS and intended to run on a SQL Server 2016 instance. The project has the ProtectionLevel of EncryptSensitiveWithPassword set. A package has a connection to a .Net Provider and this works in the package (both connection test and package run) after the SQL Server Authentication password is entered. However, if I later review the connection properties the password is missing.
Why is the password being removed when the ProtectionLevel is set as it is?

Comment: Additional information: The same project contains other packages which don't lose sensitive information upon saving and reopening. It just seems to be the .NET connection manager suffering in this way.

Comment: EDIT: I tried creating a new connection in my package using OLE DB rather than ADO.NET to see if this suffered from the same issue. It did. I tried creating an ADO.NET connection in another package in the same Project and that too had the same issue. Perhaps the password for a SQL Server authenticated connection can not be saved when EncryptSensitiveWithPassword is set.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not unsing encrypted content in SSIS packages.

Much better to use DontSaveSensitive and set up some project/package parameters and handle them in catalog project/package environments.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the values for the parameters be added to a configuration file to accompany the package? The package then pulls the values in to populate the parameters at run time? If so then I've looked into this in the past and feel that it's fine for insensitive values (file paths, folder names, etc.) but since the config file is an XML file (plain text) then it is not adequate for passwords.
Alternatively you may be suggesting that the package is loaded into the database rather than hosted in the file structure? This is not something we have previously investigated at my shop.

Comment: So I would encourage you to explore the project deployment model for ssis projects. You can store parameter values (even sensible data) into ssisdb catalog, specifically in environment settings.

Comment: The solution is configured for the project deployment model, but we currently take the packages and save them to the SQL Server file structure. Then we point an SSIS job at the package. It's a simple process but is obviously missing something as the passwords are lost along the way. I'll take another look at the Project Deployment Model expected use.